# How to convert Tuple to Async Task

Tags: c#, async-await, tuples, task

I'm doing a small application and I need help, because I do not know where the problem is.

I have not been with C # for a long time and I am learning little by little, because all this is leisure form me, no more.

I have the following Tuple that is working correctly:

```
private Tuple<int, int, int, int> CheckStatus()
        {
            int out = 0;
            int stage = 0;
            int retired = 0;
            int stop = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Start"].Value != null)
                {
                    out = out + 1;
                }
                if (Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Start"].Value != null && Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Finnish"].Value == null)
                {
                    stage = stage + 1;
                }
                if (Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Start"].Value != null && Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Finnish"].Value != null)
                {
                    stop = stop + 1;
                }
            }
            retired = GetRetirements();
            stage = stage - retired;
            return new Tuple<int, int, int,int>(out, stage, retired, stop);
        }
```

I want to pass it to asynchronous to execute an await method because now the GetRetirements method is asynchronous tasks, and change the code to this, but i have problems:

```
private async Task<Tuple<int, int, int, int>> CheckStatus()
        {
            int out = 0;
            int stage = 0;
            int retired = 0;
            int stop = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Start"].Value != null)
                {
                    out = out + 1;
                }
                if (Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Start"].Value != null && Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Finnish"].Value == null)
                {
                    stage = stage + 1;
                }
                if (Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Start"].Value != null && Dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Finnish"].Value != null)
                {
                    stop = stop + 1;
                }
            }
            retired = await GetRetirements();
            stage = stage - retired;
            return new Tuple<int, int, int,int>(out, stage, retired, stop);
        }
```

But tells me that can not find any item (item1, item2, item3, item4). I do not know where is the problem.

```
private void GetCheckStatus()
        {
            LblOut.Text = CheckStatus().Item1.ToString();
            LblStage.Text = CheckStatus().Item2.ToString();
            LblRetired.Text = CheckStatus().Item3.ToString();
            LblStop.Text = CheckStatus().Item4.ToString();
        }
```

I am doing something wrong? It's the first time I work with Tuple and I do not know the truth that it could be wrong.

Thanks you very much.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

`CheckStatus` is now an async function. To get the result you need to `await` and you likely only want to invoke the function once. Note how `async` has also been added to `GetCheckStatus` and will flow all the way up to an `async void` event handler, e.g. a button click.

```
private async Task GetCheckStatus()
{
    var status = await CheckStatus()
    LblOut.Text = status.Item1.ToString();
    LblStage.Text = status.Item2.ToString();
    LblRetired.Text = status.Item3.ToString();
    LblStop.Text = status.Item4.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You changed `CheckStatus()` to return a `Task<>`. You should probably `await` that and use the result as before.

You could also handle it in different ways, depending on your UI framework. But it comes down to "this method is now aysnc, handle it that way."

Answer (score 1):

You've made the inner call async but the outer call is not waiting for it. Try something like:

```
private async Task GetCheckStatus()
{
    var result = await CheckStatus();

    LblOut.Text = result .Item1.ToString();
    LblStage.Text = result .Item2.ToString();
    LblRetired.Text = result .Item3.ToString();
    LblStop.Text = result .Item4.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause is, that you forgot to await for the results of `CheckStatus()` before accessing the result.

It is quite conventional to end the name of async functions with async. This is to warn users not to forget that they are using async-await, and that they should await for the return value before accessing the result.

This has also the advantage that you can offer both the normal version and the async version

```
async Task<int> GetRetirementsAsync(){...}

async Task<Tuple<int, int, int, int>> CheckStatusAsync()
{
     ...
     int retired = await GetRetirementsAsync();
     return new Tuple...
}

async Task GetCheckStatusAsync()
{
    var tuple = await CheckStatusAsync();

    // process output:
    LblOut.Text = tuple.Item1.ToString();
    LblStage.Text = tuple.Item2.ToString();
    LblRetired.Text = tuple.Item3.ToString();
    LblStop.Text = tuple.Item4.ToString();
}
```

### Possible performance improvement

The reason that you want to use the GetRetirementsAsync instead of the non-async GetRetirements, is because you expect that somewhere deep inside the process has to wait idly for the results from another process, like querying database, or reading a file, or fetching data from the internet.

Instead of waiting idly, you can use async await to do other things, until you really need the results from the database.

You do this, by starting the task, without awaiting. The thread won't wait idly for the database, but continues processing your statements until you need the result and await the task.

```
private async Task<Tuple<int, int, int, int>> CheckStatus()
{
    // Get the retirements, do not await yet.
    Task<int> taskGetRetirements = GetRetirementsAsync();

    // instead of waiting idly, your thread is free to do the following:
    int out = 0;
    int stage = 0;
    int retired = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ...
    }

    // now you need the retirements; await for the task to finish
    int retired = await taskGetRetirements;
    stage = stage - retired;
    return new Tuple<int, int, int,int>(out, stage, retired, stop);
}
```